# How do I validate my html forms in HTML? No alerts, just an error display when an input field is does not contain the required pattern

Tags: javascript, html

**Phone** - text field - requires validation (Must be of the format "208-555-5555". Give this field the name phone.

**Credit Card** - text field - requires validation (must be 16 digits). Give this field the name credit_card. Must use this format: 1111 1111 1111 1111

**Credit Card Expiration Date** - text field - requires validation of data entered (i.e. valid month (1-12) and valid year (> 2020). Give this field the name exp_date. It must use this format: 01/2020.

**Submit Button** - When this button is clicked, you should validate that the first name, last name, address, phone, credit card, and expiration date fields all have been filled out. If any field is missing text, prevent the form from submitting and set the focus to the first missing text field.

```
<input type = "tel" id = "phone" class ="validate" name = "phone" pattern ="^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$"required placeholder = " +233-55-1018-495" title =" Your phone number should match the format displayed">

<div>
            <label for="cname">Name on Card</label>
            <input type="text" id="cname" name="cardname" placeholder="Nana Dickson"><br><br>
            <label for="ccnum">Credit Card</label>
            <input type="text" id="ccnum" name="credit_card" class ="validate" placeholder="1111-1111-1111-1111"><br><br>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-50">
                <label for="expyear">Credit Card Expiration Date</label>
                <input type="text"  class ="validate" id="exp_date" name="exp_date" placeholder="01/2021"
              <div class="col-50"><br>
                <label for="cvv">CVV</label>
                <input type="text" id="cvv" name="cvv" placeholder="352">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" name ="validate">
```

Comment: You already have one pattern in place which matches the phone requirements in your question (but not the placeholder in the code which states a pattern of `233-55-1018-495`). What part of the question are you having an issue with?

Comment: Research `javascript form validation` in your favorite browser search engine and you will many examples of how to do this

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState

Answer (score 0):

check this out

```
<head> 

    <script> 

        function submitform() { 

            var name =  

                document.forms["RegForm"]["Name"]; 

            var email =  

                document.forms["RegForm"]["EMail"]; 

            var phone =  

                document.forms["RegForm"]["Telephone"]; 

            var what =  

                document.forms["RegForm"]["Subject"]; 

            var password =  

                document.forms["RegForm"]["Password"]; 

            var address =  

                document.forms["RegForm"]["Address"]; 



            if (name.value == "") { 

                window.alert("Please enter your name."); 

                name.focus(); 

                return false; 

            } 



            if (address.value == "") { 

                window.alert("Please enter your address."); 

                address.focus(); 

                return false; 

            } 



            if (email.value == "") { 

                window.alert( 

                  "Please enter a valid e-mail address."); 

                email.focus(); 

                return false; 

            } 



            if (phone.value == "") { 

                window.alert( 

                  "Please enter your telephone number."); 

                phone.focus(); 

                return false; 

            } 



            if (password.value == "") { 

                window.alert("Please enter your password"); 

                password.focus(); 

                return false; 

            } 



            if (what.selectedIndex < 1) { 

                alert("Please enter your course."); 

                what.focus(); 

                return false; 

            } 



            return true; 

        } 

    </script> 



    <style> 

        div { 

            box-sizing: border-box; 

            width: 100%; 

            border: 100px solid black; 

            float: left; 

            align-content: center; 

            align-items: center; 

        } 



        form { 

            margin: 0 auto; 

            width: 600px; 

        } 

    </style> 

</head> 



<body> 

    <h1 style="text-align: center;">REGISTRATION FORM</h1> 

    <form name="RegForm" action="/submit.php" 

          onsubmit="return submitform()" method="post"> 

        <p>Name: <input type="text" 

                        size="65" name="Name" /></p> 

        <br /> 

        <p>Address: <input type="text" 

                           size="65" name="Address" /> 

      </p> 

        <br /> 

        <p>E-mail Address: <input type="text" 

                        size="65" name="EMail" /></p> 

        <br /> 

        <p>Password: <input type="text" 

                     size="65" name="Password" /></p> 

        <br /> 

        <p>Telephone: <input type="text" 

                    size="65" name="Telephone" /></p> 

        <br /> 



        <p> 

            SELECT YOUR COURSE 

            <select type="text" value="" name="Subject"> 

                <option>BTECH</option> 

                <option>BBA</option> 

                <option>BCA</option> 

                <option>B.COM</option> 

                <option>Ms</option> 

            </select> 

        </p> 

        <br /> 

        <br /> 

        <p>Comments: <textarea cols="55" 

                          name="Comment"> </textarea></p> 

        <p> 

            <input type="submit" 

                   value="send" name="Submit" /> 

            <input type="reset" 

                   value="Reset" name="Reset" /> 

        </p> 

    </form> 

</body>
```